# Xpath function to loop through repeating nodes

Tags: xpath

What XPath function works to loop through repeating XML nodes.

This is my Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record> 
  <Type>V</Type>  
  <Address> 
    <Qual>A</Qual>  
    <ID>A1</ID> 
  </Address>  
  <Address> 
    <Qual>A</Qual>  
    <ID>B2</ID> 
  </Address>  
  <Address> 
    <Qual>C</Qual>  
    <ID>C2</ID> 
  </Address>  
  <Category> 
    <EL>PO</EL> 
  </Category>  
  <Category> 
    <EL>DP</EL> 
  </Category> 
</Record>
```

I don't want to process the data if Qualf=A & ID = B2, Category =DP & Type =V

My Xpath does not work due to repeating nodes..

```
(concat(Xpath./Type,Xpath./Record/Address/Qual,Xpath./Record/Address/ID,Xpath./Record/Category/EL) != "VAB2DP"
```

so I tried

```
choose((concat(Xpath./Type,Xpath./Record/Address/Qual,Xpath./Record/Address/ID,Xpath./Record/Category/EL) != "VAB2DP"),'true','false'
```

It still does not work.

Comment: You need to specify your desired selection and the host language for your XPath engine.

Comment: You haven't told us what you want to achieve. "Looping through nodes" is a mechanism, not an outcome. You've given us two attempts that don't work -- presumably they return the wrong result -- and you've told us what you don't want to do, but you haven't told us what the desired result is.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.
It's a java based system & provides graphical editor that works on XPATH to read the source xml & extract output XML.
I receive an xml file & filter the xml's that does not meet the filter criteria through XPATH. Am not transforming the xml just filtering based on the combination.
From the Data I filter out this combination if Type|Qualf|ID|Category = "VAB2DP"

So expected result is if the data has this combination then I return it to editor as true else false. so my output what I expect is true or false. If true I don't generate the output xml.